# AWS Lambda - Multiprocessing in Python, child send() data via pipe, parent gets EOFError exception in recv()

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-multiprocessing, recv

We have a Lambda function which uses Python and multiprocessing. The task is split into chunks and each chunk is delegated to a child. When child finishes, it send() the result via shared connection (pipe).
Parent waits for all the children to complete (join()) and then does recv() on all the pipes.

Everything worked fine until the last month. Now, on each first Lambda attempt, the first parent recv() gets EOFError, and this fails our lambda execution. What is strange is that on the second attempt, everything works fine.

Child code finishes with this:

```
conn.send([csv_data])
conn.close()
```

Parent code fails on recv()

```
for process in processes:
    process.join()        

csv_data = parent_connections[0].recv()[0]
```

The parent and child connections are ends of a pipe: `parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()`

Exception that we see:

```
: EOFError
...
    csv_data = parent_connections[0].recv()[0]
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 383, in _recv
    raise EOFError
EOFError
```

When we tried moving the read from the first parent connection into the try/catch to see if the issue is only with the very first read.

```
for i in range(0, len(parent_connections)):
        try:
            result_from_child = parent_connections[i].recv()[0]
        except Exception as e:
            print("Exception while processing data from a child process: {}.".format(str(e)))
```

After this change we have noticed that first N reads are always failing and everything after that succeeds.

Any help will appreciated:

1. Why did it start to happen only recently (last month)? Maybe some change in Lambda infra?
2. Why does it happen only on the first Lambda attempt? Second attempt ALWAYS succeeds (and the first ALWAYS fails).
3. Each chunk is of a fixed size and given the amount of total work is growing, total number of processes created is also growing. Can the problem be related to this?

Comment: What are `conn` and `parent_connections[i]`? Are they sockets?

Comment: If `conn` is a socket,  `conn.send([csv_data])` will raise an exception, the send won't happen, and likely the socket closes. Since you won't tell us what these things are, its just a guess.

Comment: the connections are Pipe: ```parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()```

Comment: What module is `Pipe` from? I'm trying to figure out what data type `conn.send` is expecting. If its a `bytes` object, you'll have to serialize `[csv_data]` (or maybe just `csv_data`.

Comment: ```from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe``` 
but if there would an issue with data type it would always fail. The weirdest thing is that it ALWAYS fails on the first Lambda execution and ALWAYS succeeds on the second one.

Comment: That `Pipe` returns multiprocessing [`Connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.connection.Connection) objects which use `pickle` to serialize things. Its possible you sent something not picklable. Is the send code in a conditional that might not have run? That would also explain it.

Comment: The send node is not in a conditional. It runs at the end of child code. We also tried to surround it with try/catch but no exception observed in send() and the log lines surrounding it are showing up. I would like to emphasis that this code deterministically fails on the first Lambda execution but always succeeds on Lambda retry (auto-retry configured for Lambda).

Comment: Closing child connection after parent receives the response solved the issue for me.  --------
I am thinking that there is a delay in communicating through the pipe the first time a lambda is invoked. As child is closing the connection before parent receives, EOF Error happens.
--------
Solution is to store all child connections in a list (just like the parent connections) and close the respective child connection after parent_connections[i].recv()

Answer (score 0):

Closing child connection after parent receives the response solved the issue for me.

**Why does it happen? - A Wild Guess**

My best guess is there is a delay in communicating through the pipe the first time a lambda is invoked. As child is closing the connection before parent receives, EOFError is raised.

**Solution**

Store all child connections in a list (just like the parent connections) and close the respective child connection *after* parent receives the response.

**Modified child code**

```
child.send(data)
```

**Modified parent code**

```
results[i] = parent_connections[i].recv()
child_connections[i].close()
```